# Are the definitions of loop in CS and in programming (standard/common) identical?

Tags: terminology, recursion

Are the definitions of loop in CS and in programming (standard/common) identical?
If not, what is the main difference / what are the main differences?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any common formal general definition of "loop" in either computer science or programming.

Comment: Point me to the two definitions, then we can talk.

Answer (score 1):

Dijkstra's do loop as defined in the abstract language of guarded commands, which is a non-deterministic construct, is not found in the programming languages.

$$\begin{align}\underline{do}&\\
&\text{[] condition }1\to\text{instruction }1\\
&\text{[] condition }2\to\text{instruction }2\\
&\cdots\\
&\text{[] condition }n\to\text{instruction }n\\
\underline{od}\end{align}$$

The semantic is to

- evaluate all guards;
- choose one that is true and execute the associated instruction;
- repeat.

If no guard is true, the loop terminates.

Comment: "is not found in the programming languages"

is a broad brush. Does Promela not count as a programming language?

Comment: @Kai: no, Promela is not a programming language.

Answer (score -1):

In Mathematics and computer science, *looping* is generally associated with either some repetitive work, or with accumulated summation (bitwise, or higher logic operations).

Looping is more of an abstract view of iteration, in, say, programming - where it is very specific and depends on the language and associated compiler with programming point of view.

---

Sidenote: it is also a convenient way of writing programs to have loops rather than call some functions multiple times which is not good practice.